# Is the following thread-safe?

Tags: c#, thread-safety

I have the following code:

```
public class Info
{
    public int Data { get; set; }
}

public class Updater
{
    private static readonly object lockObject = new object();
    private Info myInfo= new Info();

    public Info MyInfo
    {
        get
        {
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                return myInfo;
            }
        }
    }

    public void UpdateInfo()
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            myInfo.Data = ReadFromExternalDevice();
        }
    }        
}
```

I have one instance of `Updater` which is accessed from two separate threads.

```
Updater updater = new Updater();
```

Thread #1 periodically calls `UpdateInfo()`.

```
updater.UpdateInfo();
```

Thread #2 periodically reads from the `Data` property of the `Info` property.

```
int latestData = updater.MyInfo.Data;
```

Is the above code in anywhere close to being thread-safe?

Comment: [What is this thing you call "thread safe"?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116957/readerwriterlock-vs-lock

Comment: I *would* note that performing `ReadFromExternalDevice()` from within the lock is probably a bad idea as it will increase your time in lock, and increases chance of contention. Save it to a local and mutate within the lock.

Comment: It is pointless to discuss thread safety without making it clear **exactly what you mean**; what scenario are you trying to guard against? even without the locks there can be no torn reads, for example. Even though it isn't the intended usage, you could achieve everything you want in terms of periodic reading via `volatile` or a forced read via `Thread.VolatileRead`.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine that

- 1st thread obtains `MyInfo` (and *leaves* the lock after `return myInfo;`)
- 1st thread starts reading `MyInfo` properties
- 2nd thread starts writing into `MyInfo`
- 1st thread keeps on reading `MyInfo` (partially changed!) properties

in this scenario the code is **not** thread safe. Even if `MyInfo` has just one `int` field it's not *thread safe*:

```
MyInfo info = Updater.Info;

Console.Write(info.Data);

// Here 2nd thread changes the info
Console.Write(info.Data);
```

Typical implementation uses `ReaderWriterLockSlim`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx

- when reading 1st thread `EnterReadLock()` reads up (*clones*) `MyInfo` into a local variable (or performs all the required procedures with `MyInfo`), then `ExitReadLock()`
- when writing 2nd thread `EnterWriteLock()` writes, then `ExitWriteLock()`

Comment: As long as `Data` is an int, he shouldn't have to worry about partial writes. Still bad form though, you are correct.

Comment: "reading into local variable" won't help with that reference type. You would need to clone the properties (`Data`) too since Thread2 does not change the _reference_ of `MyInfo`, only the properties inside that instance.

Comment: @René Vogt: Thank you! You're right it should be highlighted that *reading* means *cloning* in the context

Answer (score 1):

If you only care about **reading** the `Data` property then this implementation is... let's say... thread-safe enough.

Read and write operations on 32bit values are *atomic* in C#, so there will be no strange intermediate value in `updater.MyInfo.Data` at any point. If you have *more complex* properties that are updated, then this no longer applies. Thread 2 may have only partially updated these properties while Thread 1 is still reading on the same `MyInfo`.

**But** if you try to do something like

```
if (updater.MyInfo.Data == 5)
    updater.MyInfo.Data = 7;
```

in different threads, this is no longer guaranteed to behave as expected. As another thread may have changed the value of `Data` between the check and the assignment.

You may want to have a look at [`Interlocked.Exchange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3fxt78a(v=vs.110).aspx) for a thread-safe way to update a variable.